How to build "scipy/linalg/cython_lapack.cpython-310-riscv64-linux-gnu.so"
I run a simple script as below:
import scipy
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

#blas_dep = scipy.show_config(mode='dicts')['Build Dependencies']['blas']
#for key in blas_dep:
#    print(f"{key}:  {blas_dep[key]}")

X = np.zeros([90, 1], dtype=np.float64)
y = np.array([
    -1220.63333333,  -1168.63333333,  -904.63333333,  -618.63333333,  -14.63333333,  1331.36666667,  2438.36666667,
      4453.36666667,  3460.36666667,  1087.36666667,  -966.63333333,  -1391.63333333,  -1305.63333333,  -1210.63333333,
        -1080.63333333,  795.36666667,  1195.36666667,  1919.36666667,  334.36666667,  -1080.63333333,  -1338.63333333,
          -1444.63333333,  -1421.63333333,  -1276.63333333,  -943.63333333,  -456.63333333,  639.36666667,  1046.36666667,
            -532.63333333,  -1128.63333333,  -1112.63333333,  -1264.63333333,  -1129.63333333,  -758.63333333,  148.36666667,
              1235.36666667,  1381.36666667,  629.36666667,  -805.63333333,  -1190.63333333,  -1253.63333333,  -1244.63333333,
                -937.63333333,  133.36666667,  1821.36666667,  5231.36666667,  2764.36666667,  -802.63333333,  -1234.63333333,
                  -1016.63333333,  -1131.63333333,  -705.63333333,  104.36666667,  186.36666667,  761.36666667,  -63.63333333,
                    -733.63333333,  -1190.63333333,  -1288.63333333,  -1260.63333333,  -1020.63333333,  -753.63333333,  552.36666667,
                      1321.36666667,  2941.36666667,  1021.36666667,  -1100.63333333,  -1416.63333333,  -1450.63333333,  -1440.63333333,
                        -1430.63333333,  -1301.63333333,  -1112.63333333,  -197.63333333,  2541.36666667,  2005.36666667,  -902.63333333,
                          -1384.63333333,  -1336.63333333,  -1102.63333333,  -731.63333333,  -182.63333333,  1975.36666667,  5501.36666667,
                            4823.36666667,  2304.36666667,  346.36666667,  -1144.63333333,  -1107.63333333,  -681.63333333])

la.lstsq(X, y)

But got error log:
 ** On entry to DGELSD parameter number  7 had an illegal value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aa.py", line 25, in <module>
    la.lstsq(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/_basic.py", line 1212, in lstsq
    lwork, iwork = _compute_lwork(lapack_lwork, m, n, nrhs, cond)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/lapack.py", line 1004, in _compute_lwork
    raise ValueError("Internal work array size computation failed: "
ValueError: Internal work array size computation failed: -7

Per my investigation It get the math fuction from cython_lapack.cpython-310-riscv64-linux-gnu.so ,But looks like the wrapper give wrong parameters for unkbown reason.
So i want to know how to build this so library, I can inject some debug code to find the root cause.
My scipy version is 1.10.0 On a RISCV platform. On x86 linux it works well

Is this a driver-specific problem? SciPy allows you to specify which lapack driver is used. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq Do "gelsy", or "gelss" work?

I recommend reading the development setup guide.

I'm unable to reproduce this bug. I attempted to reproduce this using a cloud RISC V host. When running on Python 3.11 and SciPy 1.10.0, the provided program does not crash and provides the correct result.
